# An app won't register a value passed from the first ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue

What I want to do is ask for a name (input) from the first page. The second page is for tapping a button which sets the properties of the output depends on which button you tapped. The third page is the output page (a background with a label on top).

In the version of the app it works fine with two ViewControllers (1st and 3rd in the new version).

So basically you enter a name (1st page), tap a button (2nd page) and generate the output (3rd page). What I can't do is pass the data from the 1st ViewController to the 3rd View Controller.

This is the first page (selectImage being the 2nd page):

```swift
 @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "selectImage" {
            if let nextPage = segue.destinationViewController as? Results {
            nextPage.receivedFirstName = firstName.text!
            }
        }
    }
```

The 2nd page (takes no value and pass the segue [from tapping a button] to the 3rd page):

```swift
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let newVC: Results = segue.destinationViewController as! Results
    print("xxx ,%s", segue.identifier)
    newVC.receivedImage = segue.identifier!
}
```

The 3rd page (takes a value from the 1st and 2nd page and display it):

```swift
var receivedFirstName = String()
var receivedImage = String()
```

This is the layout:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUh89.png

Thanks in advance. I'm a noob and I google most of the time so please be patient with me if I ask you to clarify what it means. Really, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way.

- Page 1 has a name. It gives this name to page 2.
- Page 2 has an image. It gives this image to page 3.
- Page 3 wants a name and an image.

The breakdown is that the name is never passed on from page 2 to page 3. So, page 3 knows nothing of this which is likely why you don't see it.

You can try the following on your second view controller, assuming that you create the necessary variables to enable it (`firstName`).

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let newVC: Results = segue.destinationViewController as! Results
    print("xxx ,%s", segue.identifier)
    newVC.receivedFirstName = firstName.text!
    newVC.receivedImage = segue.identifier!
}
```

Also, you may want to look into your receivedImage value, as you are setting the segue.identifier to it which is probably not what you want.